# Is is possible to create a FEDERATED on VIEW for mysql

Tags: mysql, view, federated, federated-table, federated-storage-engine

How can I create a FEDERATED on VIEW which placed on remote server? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Why don't you just try? `CREATE TABLE federated_table(...) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://user@host:port/db/view';` If it works, it works... ;-)

There is no official documentation available, so testing would be the fastest way to answer your question.

Comment: Documentation doesn't say that FEDERATED has views limitation, and thumbs up @stefan for suggesting that you try it yourself :)

Comment: Agree. FEDERATED it is an engine. Only in tables it can be defined.

Comment: Ah, thanks. for some reason thought it is wrong because for CREATE VIEW have not CONNECTION in mysql doc. Thanks on more!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can create a FEDERATED table on a VIEW.

Here's a simple example:

```
create table t_table (
id int not null auto_increment primary key
) engine = innodb;

create or replace view v_view as select * from t_table;

create table f_fed_table (
id int not null
) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/test/v_view';
```